# Tooltip for Rep Graph Gets Stuck

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, tooltips, reputation-graph

The problem is simple, the tooltip for the rep graph well, just stays there ***after*** my mouse has moved away from the graph and has stopped hovering above it. The screenshot:

[image]

My mouse is in the blue area yet the tooltip (the one that says 240) is still there! That tooltip only shows the rep for that time when the mouse is hovering over the graph. Of course, the mouse is not and the tooltip stays as if the mouse has never moved away from that spot in the graph.

So why is the rep tooltip still there even though my mouse has moved away from the graph?

To reproduce my problem:

- Put your mouse somewhere near the right edge of your graph
- Quickly pull your mouse out of the graph by going to the right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>This is rather difficult to reproduce - I have only been able to reproduce this a a couple of times (moving the mouse *really* fast - but this is unreliable, most of the times - things just worked).</strike>

It looks like the `mouseout` event for the graph isn't firing, or that the event loop is discarding it in certain occasions.

But - given that all that happens is that the tooptip remains visible and doesn't hurt anything, and the workaround of moving the mouse over the graph and out of it will remove the tooltip, this isn't going to be fixed.

The repro I was given wasn't quite correct, with more information, this was easier to fix.

With you in the next build.

Comment: Seriously though, isn't it simple matter of resetting some timer when hovering a specific class? (`.card` in this case)

Comment: No timers involved here. Simple mousehover/mousemove on the graph itself.

Comment: OK, figured it after looking at the code: `!toolTip.is(':hover')` meaning you don't hide the tooltip if the mouse is over the tooltip itself. It got nothing to do with speed, if you are in the right edge of the graph, the tooltip sticks out of the parent placeholder. If you move the mouse over the tooltip itself, it won't be removed anymore when you move the mouse elsewhere. Fix should be either remove this condition, or add another mouseout event for the tooltip itself. What do you think?